# could not create pg-notify extension in pgadmin

Tags: node.js, postgresql, publish-subscribe, pg-notify

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_notify; could not execute this command in pgadmin .

I am getting the following error:
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/share/extension/pg_notify.control": No such file or directory

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not aware of any extension named "pg_notify" (and based on the error message, neither is your PostgreSQL installation aware of it).  There is a built-in function by that name, but a function is not an extension.  What made you think this should work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to do. pg_notify is not an extension, it is instead a function, according to this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html). The signature of the function is pg_notify(text, text). The function takes the channel name as the first argument and the payload as the second.

Alternatively, you can send a notification as:

```
NOTIFY my_channel, 'Hello, world!';
```

and listen to it as follows:

```
LISTEN my_channel;
```